# Is it "nice" in java to use map which has maps as values?

Tags: java, dictionary, software-design

For example, is it generally good to have a structure like :

```
Map <Object, Map>
```

In my case, at first sight I **do** need some kind of structure that would have for example mapping `String -> Map<...>`,
**or** it is weird and I should solve the problem somehow else?

Comment: Depends on your use-case. There's nothing necessarily wrong with it.

Comment: It's *not* nice to use [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) anywhere. At the very least, make it `Map<Object, Map<?, ?>>`.

Comment: i m not asking about row type, but about having a map having as a value.
Use case: i have some switch, for example JComboBox, and i need a separate map to be associated to each object in the list, so if i select some the coresponding map will be used.

Comment: What do you want to do with the map and what do you want to store?

Comment: flagged as too broad

Comment: @Nfear, Ok, in details:
HashMap<ObjectInJComboBox, HashMap<String, List<String>>

Comment: it is ok, as @khelwood stated, it depends on use case, and there's nothing necessarily wrong with it.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you could use some Guava datastructure with a `Pair` from Apache Commons Lang like `Table<ObjectInJComboBox, String, List<String>>` or `Multimap<Pair<ObjectInJComboBox, String>, String>`.

Comment: My general rule is that if you have time to nest generics, you have time to make a wrapper object which holds the information properly for you.

Answer (score 2):

It is not inherently good to design your data structure this way. It also is not necessarily bad.

If you will be doing lookup on the map object I would consider using a `HashMap` to improve the execution time.

From @Rafael Osipov, In cases involving concurrency consider using `ConcurrentHashMap`, for data integrity.

Comment: What should this `HashMap` hint be? That's totally unrelated and potentially "bad" ...

Comment: actually HashMap is standart implementatin of a Map. In the project in the praxis you barely see something else. Yes the question was not about it

Comment: In case the implementation involves concurrency, consider `ConcurrentHashMap` over `HashMap` for performance gain.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov no, you'd get worse "performance" from a `ConcurrentHashMap`. But you'd get *correctness*.

Comment: @AndyTurner as far as I know in concurrent environment `ConcurrentHashMap` works faster than synchronized `HashMap` instance.

Answer (score 2):

It has a few code smells for me.

1. The inner `Map` does not specify the generic types.
2. It says you need to do two look ups. I would prefer a composite key and a single lookup on a flattened map.
3. Adding to this structure must be overly complicated.
4. The key is `object`, not strongly typed.

So I would prefer to see:

```
Map<CompositeKey, ValueType>
```

Where `CompositeKey` is a class with correct equality implementation made up of the first and second keys. and `ValueType` is not a `Map`.

So for example, instead of nested maps:

```
A -> { 1 -> "ABC",
       2 -> "DEF"},
B -> { 1 -> "abc",
       3 -> "def"}
```

You have a flat map and a composite key:

```
(A,1) -> "ABC",
(A,2) -> "DEF",
(B,1) -> "abc",
(B,3) -> "def",
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing at all wrong with having a map as the value in a map. It's a fairly common way of implementing fast lookup using multiple keys.

For example, you are storing a large number of `Student` records:

```
class Student
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private School school;
}
```

You could store these in a `List<Student>` but if you want to find, say, all students at a certain school who are 16 years old it might be better to be able to say:

```
Map<School,Map<Integer,List<Student>>> index;
List<Student> subset = index.get(School.STATE_HIGH).get(16);
```

Note that there are other ways of doing the same thing such as having a separate composite key type (in my example above, representing school and age together). Also keep in mind that if your primary purpose in using a map is efficiency then, in many cases, you are probably optimising prematurely. Unless the map is storing many millions of values or you are going to be accessing them many thousands of times a second then you might want to consider a simple list that you search through.